# openshift enterprise 3.2 master logs

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I have setup OpenShift 3.2 cluster using ansible. Now I want to check master logs. Is there a way I can increase the log level to get more info? If yes how to do that?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a centralized place for Openshift services and projects logs, you can always deploy the EFK stack (which provides a Kibana UI to view any logs)

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/aggregate_logging.html